# Scroll to specific element on form submission

Tags: php, html

```html
<?php 
  if (array_key_exists( 'submit', $_POST)) { 
    if(trim($_POST[ 'g-recaptcha-response'])=="" ) { 
      $captcha_missing=true; 
    } 
  } 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#a">Section A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#b">Contact Form</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h1><span>Lorem Ipsum</span></h1>

  <h4>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h4>
  <h5>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</h5>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
  <p style="color:red">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
    mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
    pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
    ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>


  <div id="a">
    <h1>Section A</h1>
    <h4>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h4>
    <h5>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</h5>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>
    <p style="color:blue">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur auctor fringilla sapien eget dictum. Donec tristique placerat urna, eu posuere libero tincidunt ac. Mauris condimentum, leo a tempor interdum, lacus augue pellentesque erat, quis elementum
      mauris nisi tempor nibh. Duis auctor lacus at tortor venenatis maximus. Nullam ultricies orci eget mi lacinia ornare. Praesent ut efficitur massa. Ut leo ex, malesuada vel orci at, egestas consectetur justo. Vivamus rhoncus arcu sit amet nisi dignissim
      pretium. Nulla volutpat tincidunt felis. Fusce vitae aliquam metus. Suspendisse laoreet nisi mauris, a sagittis turpis convallis vel. Maecenas mollis urna id ipsum condimentum placerat. Fusce mattis enim id egestas ullamcorper. Aliquam ac porttitor
      ipsum, sed finibus velit. Nullam mattis molestie nisi a facilisis. Nunc faucibus, augue nec mollis ornare, neque neque aliquam lorem, in commodo elit dolor dapibus felis.</p>

  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <div id="b">
    <h1>Contact Form</h1>
    <h4>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h4>
    <h5>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</h5>
  </div>

  <br />
  <div>
    <form>
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxx"></div>
      <input type='email' id="email" name='email' style='width: 200px' placeholder='email'>
      <button id="submit" name="submit" type='submit'>submit</button>
      <div>
        <?php if ($captcha_missing) { ?>
        <section class="alert alert-danger" id="danger-alert">
          <p>captcha is missing</p>
        </section>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>


</html>
```

I have a webpage where a user contact form is located at the bottom part of the page. I have server side validation on the form.

When server-side validation finds an error and the page is re-displayed, is it possible to scroll to the bottom of the page where the contact form is located?

Comment: Let's see some code. We can tell you that of course it's possible, but without seeing what you're doing it's hard to give you more of an answer than that. One possibility might be ajax validation.

Comment: Thx. Let me simplify the code for easy reading then post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need JavaScript here. Let's say your contact form has a certain ID assigned to it:

```
<form id="contact-form">...</form>
```

Then, upon the unsuccessful validation, you can just refer to it in your JS:

```
<script>
    document.onload = function() {
        if (<?php echo !empty($captcha_missing) ? 'true' : 'false' ?>) {
            window.location.hash = 'contact-form';
        }
    }
<script>
```

and your browser will scroll down to your form instantly.

You could use some smooth scrolling functionality of course, via plain JS or ready-made libraries, but this would by far be the simplest and easiest way.

Comment: Thx, but my validation is done in php.  See the sample code I posted.

Comment: You mean the $captcha_missing variable? The approach would be exactly the same, I've modified my answer slightly.

Comment: it works when I added your code to the testing code I posted earlier.  Just a little issue when I added to my original code I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" at the line "document.onload.function() {"

Comment: if you don't mind, can you tell me what did you change?

Comment: It had to be `document.onload = function` instead of `document.onload.function`.

Answer (score 0):

add this line after `</section>` in your code:

```
<script>window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);</script>
```

Comment: did you mean after <section class="alert alert-danger" id="danger-alert">
          <p>captcha is missing</p>
        </section>

Comment: yes, of course.
after `</section>` and before closing `php`

Comment: Note that this may not work for you very well if the form is somewhere in the middle of a long page, because this code simply scrolls the page to the bottom, where this form may or may not be located.

Comment: you are right, But this is the case what he wants. scroll to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do is the autofocus feature in html form submission.

```
<input type="text" name="name" autofocus />
```